# Failed to retrieve COM class

Tags: c#, uwp, raspberry-pi3

When attempting to access the Debug section of my C# UWP app's properties, the menu fails to load with an error exclaiming:

**An error occurred trying to load the page.
Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {2D0A16C9-53D9-42C1-BCC2-8D2A135E2163} failed due to the following error: 8007007e The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E).**

Since then I have tried updating all of my pending updates in Visual Studio to no avail. This menu loads properly in my installation of VS 2013 on the same device.

I do not get this as an error when attempting to compile my application. The application runs as it should on my system. The issue is that I would like to run the application on my new Raspberry Pi over my wireless network. To do so I have to access the Debug menu in the application properties.

Also my application does not have the words "Local Machine" attached to the button that runs the application. It simply says "Start". Shouldn't I be able to select "Remote Machine" from the drop down?

Thanks so much for your time

Comment: A file disappeared from your disk, it is C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Phone Tools\CoreCon\12.0\Bin\ConMan2.dll.  You'll have to run the VS installer again, hopefully the repair option will put it back.  And of course you'll want to check the health of the disk, files disappearing without a trace is never a good sign.

Comment: Okay thanks. I don't seem to have the CoreCon folder in the first place. I'm running the installer again now. Thanks so much. I'll try to keep you updated on whether or not the repair option works. If not, I'll probably uninstall and reinstall visual studio.

Comment: Thanks so much. I just finished repairing my installation, and everything seems to be back to normal!